# Receiving and storing HTML entities with AngularJS

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I am trying to store and receive HTML content (via HTML editor) with my AngularJS WebApp.
However, the code is shown as plain text.

JSApp:

```
$scope.SkipValidation = function (value) {
    var decoded = $("#showtext").html(value).text();
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(decoded);
};
// Retrieving the object with the content
$scope.getTemplate = function () {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'api/template.php?id=' + $routeParams.id
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.template = response.data;
        var index = $scope.types.findIndex(x => x.name==$scope.template.type)
        $scope.selected = $scope.types[index];
        $scope.content = $scope.template.content;
        $("#templatebutton").hide();
        $("#newtemplateform :input").prop("disabled", true);
        $(".actions").show();
    }, function (response) {
        alert(response.data, response.status);
    });
};
```

And finally the HTML

```
                    <div class="shown">
                        <div id="showtext" ng-bind-html="content"></div>
                    </div>
```

The code in the database is stored like this:
(After the POST in php:)

```
$template->content = htmlentities($_POST['content']);
```

And the result in my DB is:

```
&lt;b&gt;&lt;u&gt;&quot;12.10 On-Going Submission of &quot;&quot;Made Up&quot;&quot; Samples.&quot;&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/b&gt;
```

**UPDATE:**
The skipValidation() methods started to work! So now my text is shown correctly.

However now I get HTML tags in my summernote textarea due to:

```
$('$templatecontent').html($('.summernote').summernote("code",$scope.content));
```

How can I show the formatted text instead of the text with tags like  et cetera?

**UPDATE 2:**

Still no progress, however I tried to JSON_DECODE the $scope.content, and I've tried to use Angular-Summernote but apparently that's not compatible with my version (0.8.2).

**UPDATE 3:**

I found out that calling the following function when Summernote is loaded works;

```
var html = "<b>hello</b>";
 $('#templatecontent').summernote('code',html);
```

However using a dynamic variable that is loaded on forehand doesn't work:

```
  var html = $scope.template.content;
     $('#templatecontent').summernote('code',html);
```

The result of this code is basically "**hello**" if that was to be the content of $scope.template.content. It still does not render correctly.

Comment: It's being html encoded, probably by htmlentities - can you avoid using that, or use something else that will give you the text submitted?

Comment: You're talking about storing it right? Because I do have to escape it somehow to avoid injection? I also tried htmlspecialchars.

Comment: You can store it as html encoded if you like, you'll just need to unencode it when it comes out of the database.

Comment: How is it possible to dynamicaly unencode? Right now the tags are being displayed instead of unencoded. I do use $sce.trustAsHtml(decoded);

Comment: I got it working with the $sce.trustAsHtml. However, now my summernote editor shows the HTML Tags instead of formatted text. How can I de/un/re/encode the value to summernote again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original post you can find some of the efforts I tried to show HTML formatted text, and how to load the same text into summernote with rendering the html tags visually.

After several attempts I found that changing

```
<textarea  class="form-control " id="templatecontent" name="content" ng-model="template.content"  style="resize:none;"></textarea>
```

to

```
<textarea  class="form-control " id="templatecontent" name="content" ng-bind-html="SkipValidation(template.content)"  style="resize:none;"></textarea>
```

(Note the ng-bind-html) worked. I assumed the ng-bind-html directive only worked for showing html-formatted text in a HTML element and not summernote. But hey, guess what.. Summernote exists out of HTML elements (duh...)

Thanks to those who helped!

The complete code to show and edit the text is:

```
 <div class="editor">
                        <textarea  class="form-control " id="templatecontent" name="content" ng-bind-html="SkipValidation(template.content)"  style="resize:none;"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shown">
                        <p ng-bind-html="SkipValidation(template.content)"></p>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It can be rendered into correct html using ngSanitize. It has to be injected into the module as given below. Have a look.

```
  angular.module('sanitizeExample', ['ngSanitize'])
           .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
             $scope.snippet =
               '<p style="color:blue">an html\n' +
               '<em onmouseover="this.textContent=\'PWN3D!\'">click here</em>\n' +
               'snippet</p>';
             $scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function() {
               return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.snippet);
             };
           }]);
```

You can get more details about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)..

And please correct me if I misinterpreted your question.

---

### UPDATE

```
function htmlToPlaintext(text) {
  return text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
}
```

usage :

```
var plain_text = htmlToPlaintext( your_html );
```

---

#### With angular.js :

```
angular.module('myApp.filters', []).
  filter('htmlToPlaintext', function() {
    return function(text) {
      return  text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
    };
  }
);
```

use :

```
<div>{{myText | htmlToPlaintext}}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using a ngSanitize function (for me its called SkipValidation) and has the same logic as yours. The problem is however that the tags are still displayed instead of rendered into summernote. Check update 3 in the mainpost for the status of the problem right now, which I find quite odd.

Comment: @Kraishan did you try `ng-bind-html`?

Comment: Yes, for showing the html text in a <p> element it works. The only thing right now is rendering the html text in a summernote element.

Comment: This does not work, because summernote is initiated in that div. So right now I still get <b>Hello</b> as text instead of bold Hello.